# - Cannot use v-for on stateful component root element because it renders multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Getting the error the error in the title, I am new to vue.js and I cannot figure it out

Cannot debug this for the life of me, can somebody help?

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#location-box',
    data: {
        locations: [
            {
                name: "Europe",
                desc: "Loren ipsum"
            },
            {
                name: "America",
                desc: "Loren ipsum"
            }
        ],
    },
})
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="location-section">
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="location-grid-container">
            <div id="info-box" class="outline">

            </div>
            <div>
            <div id="location-box" v-for="location in locations" class="outline">
            <h1>{{location.name}}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The root element that you pass to the `el` option of your `new Vue` app must be unique, and serve only as a placeholder.

Then you can use Vue directives on its children.

So in your case you could do:

```html
<div id="location-section">
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="location-grid-container">
      <div id="info-box" class="outline">
      </div>
      <div id="location-box"><!-- Root element for your Vue app -->
        <div v-for="location in locations" class="outline">
          <h1>{{location.name}}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#location-box',
  // etc.
});
```